# Regex replace pattern with first char of match & second char in caps

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say i have the following string:

```
"a test-eh'l"
```

I want to capitalize the start of each word. A word can be separated by a space, apostrophe, hyphen, a forward slash, a period, etc. So I want the string to turn out like this:

```
"A Test-Eh'L"
```

I'm not too worried about getting the first character capitalized from the gsub call, as that's easy to do after the fact. However, when I've been using IRB and match method, I only seem to be getting one result. When i use a scan, it collects the matches, but the problem is I cannot really do much with it, as i need to replace the contents of the original string.

Here's what i have so far:

```
"a test-eh'a".scan(/[\s|\-|\'][a-z]/)
=> [" t", "-e", "'a"]

"a test-eh'a".match(/[\s|\-|\'][a-z]/)
=> #<MatchData " t">
```

Then if i try the pattern using gsub:

```
"a test-eh'a".gsub(/[\s|\-|\'][a-z]/, $1)
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
```

In javascript, i would normally use parenthesis instead of square brackets on the front section. However, i wasn't getting correct results in the scan call when doing so.

```
"a test-eh'a".scan(/(\s|\-|\')[a-z]/)
=> [[" "], ["-"], ["'"]] 

"a test-eh'a".gsub(/(\s|\-|\')[a-z]/, $1)
=> "a'est'h'"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use 1st captured group in replacement string like that: `'\1'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"a test-eh'a".gsub(/(?:^|\s|-|')[a-z]/) { |r| r.upcase }
# => "A Test-Eh'A"
```